# On Debian Mate, Visual Studio Code renders fonts badly

Tags: debian, visual-studio-code, mate-desktop

Since a few days ago, Visual Studio Code badly displays fonts. I'm currently under Debian Buster with Mate as the desktop environment. As I don't know how to correctly describe the display, here are some screenshots (it's particularly visible in the fourth one) :

- [File example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdsk1.png)
- [A zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PIh8.png)
- [When I open the View menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFsSr.png)
- [A zoom (again)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRCcf.png)

Here are the actions I remember having done before noticing the problem :

- Creating a backup with Back In Time (I doubt the problem comes from this one)
- Upgrading from Debian "Stretch" 9 to Debian "Buster" 10
- Installing Firefox Quantum, libfontconfig1, fontconfig-config and libnss3 from Sid (following [this site](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-firefox-quantum-on-debian-stretch-linux))

And, finally, here are the tests I've made around this problem :

- Using a new desktop environment (KDE Plasma) : the problem does not occur but I'd like to keep Mate
- Changing Mate's window manager (from Marco to OpenBox and awesome) : the problem still occurs
- Removing Visual Studio Code, purging it and be sure that every config file is gone, then reinstalling Code : the problem is still there
- Downgrading Firefox and the other packages mentioned above : still there

Comment: This question has so many OS-specific components that it belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about Super User. I found my answer [there](https://superuser.com/questions/1265411/font-rendering-issue-in-visual-studio-code): it was just a problem with libfreetype6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from libfreetype6. Copying the version from the stable release of Debian into `/usr/share/code` solved the problem. [Source](https://superuser.com/questions/1265411/font-rendering-issue-in-visual-studio-code)